# Where are all the obelisks?

Tags: the-witness

I'm trying to find all the hidden puzzles in the game. The obelisks (black hexagonal pillars) are really helpful hints for that and I'm pretty sure I've seen all of them at least once before, but searching the entire island again each time I want to check them out is getting a bit tedious. Unfortunately, I can't find a list of all obelisk locations online that doesn't also include spoilers for the actual hidden puzzles.

So: how many obelisks are there and where can they be found on the island?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a list of the obelisks [on IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-witness/Environmental_Puzzles), that I could use to track down their actual locations. The following spoiler block contains all the obelisks, their locations and screenshots of them. I've taken the screenshots in a fresh savegame such that they don't reveal any hidden puzzles. The spoiler block also contains the map with all obelisks taken from the IGN wiki.

> There are **6** obelisks in total and they can all be reached immediately after solving the first 8 puzzles. I'm using the names given to them on IGN.
>
>  **Town Obelisk:** As the name says this one is in the town. It's in a small overgrown ruin near the harbour.
>
>  [image]
>
>  **Desert Obelisk:** This one is between the desert and the pink trees (known as the orchard), in front of the peninsula with the red gate:
>
>  [image]
>
>  **Quarry Obelisk:** This one where the quarry, the lake and the orange wood meet.
>
>  [image]
>
>  **River Obelisk:** On the side of the mountain, next to the river, in front of the waterfall.
>
>  [image]
>
>  **Tree House Obelisk:** This one is actually easier to reach from keep than the tree house area (it's right between them).
>
>  [image]
>
>  **Monastery Obelisk:** On a few rocks next to the monastery/Asian garden area. You can reach this from the jungle by stepping out onto those rocks.
>
>  [image]
>
>  And finally, here is the full map taken from the IGN wiki:
>
>  [image]